# Custom countdown timer Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I want to create a custom countdown timer in Android Studio but I want it to have a longer duration/interval between 2 counts rather than a normal countdown timer. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the countDownInterval argument, you can change the interval between two ticks:

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // do sth here...
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // do sth here...
    }
};
```

For example by setting it to 2000, the timer ticks every 2 seconds.
To start or stop timer:

```
mCountDownTimer.start();
mCountDownTimer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {//initial interval is one second
            private int i = 0;

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                i++;
                if (i % 2 == 0) {//if you want a longer interval to do something
                    //practical interval is now two seconds, change as you want.
                    ......
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                    .....
            }
        }.start();
```